# USB and 9V DC out of a sealed box

Tags: wiring

I´m making a small box that has to be completely sealed with no holes on them. On the inside of the box is a circuit board  which requires 9V DC plug and there is also a USB connection from the board. So basically, I have to lead a USB cable and a 9V DC plug out of the sealed box.

What is an efficient way to do that? Can I do combine the wiring somehow and lead them through a single hole on the box?

How is this generally done?

Comment: Have you considered a 6-conductor cable?

Answer (score 1):

Using a cable gland is quite a normal way of achieving high sealing. You can combine the cables if you think this will work or use two cable glands: -

[image]

Here's one from Farnell (UK) that indicates its Ingress Protection (IP Rating): -

[image]

[IP 68](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Code) means "Dust tight" and suitable for immersion in water beyond 1 metre

There is also an IP 69 standard: -

> German standard DIN 40050-9 extends the IEC 60529 rating system
>   described above with an IP69K rating for high-pressure,
>   high-temperature wash-down applications.[7] Such enclosures must not
>   only be dust tight (IP6X), but also able to withstand high-pressure
>   and steam cleaning. The test specifies a spray nozzle that is fed with
>   80°C water at 8–10 MPa (80–100 bar) and a flow rate of 14–16 L/min.
>   The nozzle is held 10–15 cm from the tested device at angles of 0°,
>   30°, 60° and 90° for 30s each. The test device sits on a turntable
>   that rotates once every 12s (5rpm). The IP69K test specification was
>   initially developed for road vehicles, especially those that need
>   regular intensive cleaning (dump trucks, cement mixers, etc.), but
>   also finds use in other areas (e.g., food industry, car wash centres).

I believe you can get a few suppliers to supply IP69 gland. [Here](http://1001389.en.makepolo.com/products/IP69-Nylon-Cable-Gland-p13891239.html) is a link to one.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question:how would I get the USB and DC plug connectors through the gland? Do I have to cut the wire and solder it back  on the other side?

Comment: If you are looking for something that is more than just weatherproof then yes. The gland is the technology for this and there are some sealed USB connectors as well I believe that may do the job. Inside the box you can jump from your PCB with the desired connectors to a terminal block that would suit the incoming robust cable.